# CGRect change origin in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nd6q9OmDppJrxjZIRODzffVDiBXKnB_e/view?usp=sharing

**I'd like to change the position of the 'origin' like a picture for compose the watermark.**

Bellow is my code.

```
var watermark = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
var newHeight = filteredImage.image?.size.height
var newWidth = filteredImage.image?.size.width

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width:newWidth!, height:newHeight!))

watermark.draw(in: CGRect(x:-0, y:-0, width:400, height:300))

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

watermark = newImage!

filter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")
filter!.setValue(CIImage(image: watermark), forKey: "inputImage")
filter!.setValue(coreImage1, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
```

**How should I change my code?**

Comment: Change the `x` and `y` of the `origin` of the rect? I don't understand what you're asking exactly

Comment: Oh, you want to place it to the right bottom corner? Something like `x: newWidth - watermark.width, y: newHeight - watermark.height`?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place watermark to right bottom corner, use:

```
var watermark = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!
var newSize = filteredImage.image.size

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

watermark.draw(in: CGRect(
    x: newSize.width - watermark.image.width,
    y: newSize.height - watermark.image.height,
    width: watermark.image.width,
    height: watermark.image.height
))

...
```

Changing the origin is possible but impractical in this case.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But what's the more practical way?

Comment: @travisIcecream This is the most practical way, it's not changing the origin. The origin is still in the left bottom corner. The other way is to use `context.translate(newSize.width, newSize.height)` to actually move the origin and then use `x: -watermark.image.width, y: -watermark.image.height` to draw relative to the new origin.

Comment: Oh I see!! Thank you so much! Your explanation was very helpful to me! :)